# Why cannot user ng-model with $cookies (Angular 1.3)

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I thought this would be a super simple thing but it turns out its not.

How come this code below won't work, I would think if I set the model to a cookie, it would set the cookie, just like it would set the var, and on get it gets the cookie:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wz3kgak3/5/

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($cookies) {
    var THIS = this;
});
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as mc">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="mc.$cookies.user" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <hr>
    <h1>Hello {{mc.$cookies.user}}!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

$cookies is a service you cannot use it in the view, if you want to set the user you have to use ,

```
$cookies.put ('user', this.user);
```

see , https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies